# Bind three select menus together

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have JSON data in this link below:

First select menu belongs to series. Second select menu belongs to chapters and third belongs to pages. When you change first select menu Naruto to One Piece it has load One Piece chapters and last One Piece chapter. How can i achieve this?

```
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="myOption" ng-options="manga.seri for manga in bilgiler1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Manga</option>
    <option></option>
</select>
<select class="browser-default">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Chapter</option>
    <option></option>
</select>
<select class="browser-default">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Page</option>
    <option></option>
</select>
<img ng-repeat="" ng-src="/{{}}">
```

Javascript:

```
.factory('MMG', function($http){
    var fveg= {};
    var url = 'http://api.mangayurdu.com/manga?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
    fveg.adlar = $http.jsonp(url);
    return fveg;
})
.controller('nbgCtrl',function  ($scope, MMG) {
    MMG.adlar.success(function(loHemen) {
        $scope.bilgiler1 = loHemen;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep an array of all the mangas where each manga object keeps its chapters and each chapter keeps its page count.

Then use `ng-repeat` to run through the mangas as you already did, then run through the chapters of the selected manga and then over the pages of the selected chapter.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsLyyekz/2/) of the concept.

Comment: I have no coding experince man I just help with some friend of mine for their Fansub website so could you show some examples?

Comment: i added a fiddle to my answer

Comment: it didn't save the fiddle

Comment: Checking but My JSON data doesnt have `number` key. Could you update it that way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92359/discussion-between-shamun-and-nasuh).

Answer (score 2):

you need some objects in your controller

```
selectedManga = {}; 
selectedChapter = {}
```

then you add this to your first select

```
ng-options="manga.randomword as manga.seri for manga in bilgiler1" 
ng-model="selectedManga";
ng-change="selectedChapter = {}; // to reset the selected chapter if manga changes
```

in the second select you add

```
ng-options="chapter.yol as chapter.klasor for chapter in selectedManga"
ng-model="selectedChapter"
```

in selectedChapter you have the array with the images and can show them in the third selectbox and so on

Comment: Thank you this works. But cant manage code last select menus. Like this: `ng-options="chapterx.yol for chapterx in selectedChapter" ng-model="selectedChapter`. And how am i gonna use paths of images i mean "yol".